# Why does my JFrame move to the background after closing modal JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

Edit: Updated question including a MRE and an answer can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63518148/jframe-moves-to-the-background-for-some-reason)

I'm pretty lost after stumbling across this issue and finding no way to resolve it myself.

**Description:**

I have an application which has a Java Swing GUI. All the communication to the GUI is done via custom Events, mostly created by the main program, which are then processed by a Controller to control the GUI.

One event I have will trigger the Controller to open a custom Modal JDialog which acts just as a "please wait while the stuff in the background is being processed". So after the background task is finished, an Event will trigger the Dialog to dispose, to make the main GUI frame accessible again.

**The issue:**

When the Dialog is disposed, the main Frame will magically be set to the background. Not minimized, not completely in the background of all open windows, but actually in the background of the last open window. I'm completely lost on how and why this happens.

The important parts of the Controller class look vaguely like this:

```
class Controller {
    private ModalWaitDialog dialog;
    private JFrame frame;

    private void createMainFrame() {

        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // create frame
                frame = new JFrame();
                // make the frame visible
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void showWaitPopup(String msg) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                modalWaitDialog = new ModalWaitDialog(frame, message);
                modalWaitDialog.showDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    // after this was executed, my frame will be set in the background
    private void endWaitPopup() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (modalWaitDialog != null) {
                    modalWaitDialog.dispose();
                    modalWaitDialog = null;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I know this is not a MCVE, but maybe somebody knows how and why this happens.

Edit:

I added a WindowFocusListener to the Frame and added some print statements to the endWaitPopup, and called `invokeAndWait` to further see what is happening. The following is the result:

```
private void endWaitPopup() {
    System.out.println("In EndWaitPopup");
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                System.out.println("EndWaitPopup... run started");
                // implement as if it could be called if no wait popup is available
                if (modalWaitDialog != null) {
                    System.out.println("Disposing the modal dialog");
                    modalWaitDialog.dispose();
                    modalWaitDialog = null;
                }
                System.out.println("End of EndWaitPopup");
            }
        });
    } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> In EndWaitPopup
> +++Focus of Frame lost+++
> EndWaitPopup... run started
> Disposing the modal dialog
> End of EndWaitPopup
> ```

Comment: Do you mean that the JFrame loses the/its focus? Which app does receive the focus then?

Comment: I don't see where you set the parent of the dialog to be the frame.

Comment: @jmizv Yes. The JFrame loses the focus and goes in the background of the last app that was selected. For example just like what would happen for Alt+Tab on Windows. So it doesn't go fully in the background, but rather just behind the last window that had focus before the Frame.

Comment: @camickr The frame is being set as the parent for the dialog. As this was just a vague sketch of the Controller class, I didn't include it. I know that you are very knowledgable in Swing, did you ever encounter this kind of behavior? I took a lot of time to narrow it down, but I can't figure out why this would happen when disposing of the dialog.

Comment: @camickr I also added an Edit to maybe further clarify.

Comment: Additionally, I found something that might also have to do with it. Together with the `EndWaitPopup` the JFrame will be Enabled back (after being disabled when the "wait" dialog starts). This might also be involved. But I still don't know why.

Comment: I was able to create a MCVE for the issue. I voted to close this question as it was too broad and vague and asked an updated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63518148/jframe-moves-to-the-background-for-some-reason).

Comment: *did you ever encounter this kind of behavior? * - no. I know of no reason why you would need to set the frame disabled before showing the dialog. A modal dialog will prevent you from accessing the frame until it is closed. This is standard UI design.